# How to load a page in div dynamically in MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my `MVC` app, i have a following div:

```
<div id='loader' > </div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="OK" />
<script>
$("#button").on("click", function(){  
    // want to load MyPage.html here in loader div
    alert('121');
    return false; 
});    
</script>
```

while there is another page `MyPage.html` that contains `HTML` contents .i.e. `table`.

**MyPage.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td> Data1</td> <td> Data2</td> <td> Data3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to `Load` `MyPage.html` on click event of button. how to fix it ?

Comment: Fix what? You didn't try anything, what could be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){  
    $.get('MyPage.html',function(data){
      $('#loader').html(data);
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax.BeginForm()`

sample : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('MyPage.html').success(function(data) {
     $('div.content').html(data);
});
```

OR

```
// Direct
$('div.content').load('MyPage.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use load() Method in jquery.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#loader").load("MyPage.html");
});
```